# How can I check if an element has a CSS class that matches a value in an array?

Tags: theming, 9

In Drupal 9, I'm trying to check if an element has a certain css class using `hasClass()`.

```
<p{{ attributes }}>Does this element have my css class?</p>

{% if attributes.hasClass('my-css-class') %}
  <p>Yes it does!</p>
{% else %}
  <p>No it doesn't.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Instead of checking for one class, I would like to check if my element has one of the classes contained in an array.

```
{%
  set my_css_classes = [
    'class-one',
    'class-two',
    'class-three'
  ]
%}
```

How can I check if my element has a class that matches one (or more) of the values in the `my_css_classes` array?

Comment: Loop over my_css_classes and check for each class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, a simple loop should do:

```
{% set class_match = null %}

{% for class in my_css_classes %}
  {% if attributes.hasClass(class) %}
    {% set class_match = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if class_match %}
  <p>Match exists</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you @Prestoraurus! Works like a charm.